# Number of possible initial grids

Tags: combinatorics, transformation, combinatorial-geometry

A hypothetical function F takes a two-dimensional grid and gives a grid of one fewer row and column.

The following transformation takes place in this hypothetical function

Value of grid[i][j] can be converted to 1 by transformation if and only if values in ONE of the element grid[i][j], grid[i][j+1], grid[i+1][j] or grid[i+1][j+1] is 1. If more than one element from those elements are 1, then grid[i][j] will be 0 after transformation.

So, for example

> 0 1 0 0
>
> 0 0 1 0
>
> 0 0 0 1
>
> 1 0 0 0

can be transformed into another grid given below by function F

> 1 0 1
>
> 0 1 0
>
> 1 0 1

Given F(X)=Y, I want to find distinct number of X grids possible for the given grid Y.
For the above example, number of X possible is equal to 4.

How can I solve questions of such types? Is there any theory to solve such questions?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please take a look at [how to format mathematics here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I'm afraid I missed something. If one of the elements to the right (m[i][j+1]), bottom (m[i+1][j]) or right-bottom (m[i+1][j+1]) equal 1, the value is transformed into 1, unless all three elements ("more than two") equal 1, in which case the value is transformed into 0. In all other cases (no elements equal 1 or exactly two elements equal 1), the value remains the same. Should the resulting matrix not be [1 1 1; 0 1 1; 1 0 1] in this case?

Comment: @jvdhooft I'm afraid you missed something. The value transforms to zero in four cases
1) m[i][j], m[i][j+1], m[i+1][j] and m[i+1][j+1] all are zero.
2)Two of them are one.
3)Three of them are one.
4)All of them are one.

Comment: The description in your comment above doesn't match what you wrote in your post. I suggest you edit your post.